# How to override the nav a css inside the ul, i don't want to do add the class (no_pad) everytime

Tags: html, css

I want to override the nav a css using something like nav> li >a
I don't want to manually add some class and them override from there.

```
<style>
nav a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 25px;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    font-size: 1.35em;
}
</style>

<nav>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="" class="no_pad">CSS</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" class="no_pad">Item 11</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="no_pad">Item 12</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item 13</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item 14</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<nav>
```

Comment: check this out css selectors https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp that will give you a help